# Pythonanywhereへ既に作ったアプリを上書きしたい

Tags: python, git, django

Djangoで作ったアプリをPythonanywhereへデプロイ後、
再編集して上書きしたところ、以下のようなエラーがでてしまいました。
原因がわからず、上書き方法がわかりません。

```
WARNING: Package(s) not found: django
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hogehohe/.local/bin/pa_autoconfigure_django.py", line 47, in <module>
    main(arguments['<git-repo-url>'], arguments['--domain'], arguments['--python'], nuke=arguments.get('--nuke'))
  File "/home/hogehohe/.local/bin/pa_autoconfigure_django.py", line 36, in main
    project.update_settings_file()
  File "/home/hogehohe/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pythonanywhere/django_project.py", line 74, in update_settings_file
    new_django = version.parse(self.virtualenv.get_version("django")) >= version.parse("3.1")
  File "/home/hogehohe/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pythonanywhere/virtualenvs.py", line 32, in get_version
    output = subprocess.check_output(commands).decode()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 356, in check_output
    **kwargs).stdout
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 438, in run
    output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/home/hogehohe/.virtualenvs/hogehohe.pythonanywhere.com/bin/pip', 'show', 'django']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

以下は参考記事です。
まずは下記の記事を参考にAppをデプロイしました。
[Djangoの使い方～デプロイ編②～](https://qiita.com/connecrew-sugiyama/items/5080052e564334672bd6)

こちらは成功し、使用できていたのですが
変更箇所がでてきて、VSコードで編集後、
Git コミット、Pushし、今度は以下を参考に上書きしました。
[Pythonanywhere上で、環境変数を設定してWebアプリをデプロイする手順](https://www.kageori.com/2020/09/pythonanywhereweb.html)

具体的には以下のコマンドを試しました。

> もし、既に作ったアプリを上書きしたい場合は、
>
> ```
> $ pa_autoconfigure_django.py https://github.com/[ユーザー名]/[プロジェクト名].git --nuke
> ```
>
> と、末尾に `--nuke` をつける。

こちらのコマンドを実行後、上記のエラーがでました。
ネット検索しても一致する情報がなかなかでてこず困っております。
何かわかる方がおりましたらアドバイスいただけますと助かります。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

「pa_autoconfigure_django.py」は実行すると、仮想環境を自動的に構築します。その際、仮想環境で使用するパッケージは、指定したgithubリポジトリにある「requirements.txt」の内容を基にインストールを行います。
今回の場合、djangoのパッケージがインストールされていないことでエラーが出ていると考えられるため、「requirements.txt」に以下の文言を入れれば、解決すると思われます。

Django~=2.2.4
（文言は、djangogirlsから取ってきたので、バージョンは適宜合ったものに修正してください）

Comment: ありがとうございます。解決しました。